# How to Fix a File Output PrintStream that Only Produces Blank Files

Tags: java

The program outputs on my console as intended, but it can only create blank output files right now.  I can't figure out what is wrong.  Here is the method that I believe is the source of my troubles:

```
    public static PrintStream getOutputPrintStream(Scanner console) {
           PrintStream output = null;
           System.out.print("Output file? ");
           String outputFileName = console.nextLine();          
           File f = new File(outputFileName);
           while(f.exists()){
               System.out.print("File already exists. Overwrite it? (y/n) ");
               if(console.nextLine().charAt(0) == 'y') {
                   break;
              }
               else {
                   System.out.print("Output file? ");
                   outputFileName = console.nextLine(); 
                   f = new File(outputFileName);
              }             
           }
           try {            
               output = new PrintStream(new File(outputFileName));      
               } 
               catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   System.out.println("Output file cannot be created.");
               }
           return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in this code.  This code simply opens the file ... without writing anything to it.

Look at the code that uses the `output` object.  Make sure that it writes something, and make sure that it calls `close()` on it when it is finished writing.

Comment: Can you give me an idea on how to accomplish this?  I'm a bit of a programming novice right now.

Comment: Accomplish what?  To write to a `PrintStream` call `print(...)` or `println(...)`.  To close it ... call `close()`.  To get information on how to use an object's methods, read the javadocs.

Comment: I figured it out just now.  Thanks, though, man.  Your advice was rather helpful.